# Using encapsulated Lambda functions in Python to calculate the sum of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda, map-function

So I tried this

```
z=0
x = [2, 3, 4]
y = [4, 5]
t = map(lambda v : map(lambda w : v + w, y), x)
# t == [[6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]
z = sum(t, [])
```

our loops iterate through x and y and add the sum of the values to z. For some reason, I get the error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "map") to list
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Function `map` returns a `map object`, not a list. Function `sum` expects a sequence of lists. You should convert the map objects to lists:

```
t = map(lambda v : list(map(lambda w : v + w, y)), x)
z = sum(t, [])
#[6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

As a more readable and efficient alternative, you can use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

t = [[6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]

res = list(chain.from_iterable(t))

print(res)

[6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9]
```